# Excel calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help with putting together an Excel formula.

I invested in a stock over a period of time. I am trying to determine the average number of years I held that stock based on its purchase date and amount.

Here is an example:

If I had bought $10,000 worth of IBM each year in Jan 2019, Jan 2020, Jan 2021, Jan 22, and Jan 23, the average number of years I held IBM would be 2 years plus (4 years from Jan 2014 to Jan 2023, and 4 more months).

But if I had bought $10,000 in Jan 2019, but only $2,000 each of the following years, my average number of years would have to be more than 2 years since my oldest investment was so much larger.

I don't have enough background in math to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Calculate what percentage each purchase is of your total
2. Multiply that percentage by the years you held each purchase
3. Add up those results

Years held is `=DAYS(TODAY(),A2)/365`

Weight is `=B2/SUM($B$2:$B$6)`

Weighted Years Held is `=C2*D2`

Average Years Held is `=AVERAGE(C2:C6)`

Average Weighted Years Held is `=SUM(E2:E6)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like @kevin beat me to it while I was writing this, but I'll post it anyway to show the comparison between your two examples. Use a weighted average, where the age is weighted by the dollar amount. In this example I measure age in days instead of years, to get around the part-year issue for 2023. Convert to years as @kevin did if you want.

```
C2:  =TODAY() - A2
D2:  =B2 * C2
B7:  =SUM(B2:B6)
D7:  =SUM(D2:D6)
D8:  =D7/B7
```

Your intuition is correct, where the average age in the second example is 1173 days, versus the 848 days in your first example.

[image: Spreadsheet calcs]

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. Will try both yours and Kevin's solutions.